# jq get all unique values for a given key in a list of objects

Tags: json, unique, jq

Let's say I have an endpoint that returns the following array:

```
[
  {"name": "Joe", "age": 21},
  {"name": "Steve", "age": 27},
  {"name": "Michelle", "age": 32},
  {"name": "Joe", "age": 23},
]
```

I know I can get all names using the following command (using httpie):

```
http https://some-endpoint | jq '.[] | .name'

# output
Joe
Steve
Michelle
Joe
```

How can I get all unique names (so there are no duplicates)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the input is valid JSON, the following jq program will yield an array of the distinct names:

```
map(.name) | unique
```

If the input has superfluous commas as in the sample shown, you might wish to consider using a preprocessor, such as `any-json` or `hjson`.